# In subversion, someone deleted a file and added it back with changes in a single commit, how do I fix this?

Tags: svn

Someone made a single subversion commit that delete a file, and added a new file with the same name, that consists of the original files along with ~155 new lines.

(I have no idea how they managed to do this.)

Now 'svn log' only shows the history going back to that commit, and I have to jump through hoops if I want to diff revisions of that file from before and after the point in time that they did this. (E.g. 'svn diff url@oldrev url@newrev' instead of 'svn diff -r n:m')

A handful of commits have been made to this file after this happened. (Around 3).

How can I fix this?

I'm using the command line 'svn' client on Linux.

Comment: It's been a while since I've done this, but can you delete that file again, revert the changes in the revision with the original deletion (ignoring other changes), and reapply the 3 recent commits?

Comment: I don't want to do anything I'm not sure about, and mess up the shared repository further. I'm not sure how I revert the file to before it was deleted, and do it in a way that svn recognizes as the original file with history. If I could do that, then reapplying the rest of the changes should be easy to do.

Comment: Yep - that's certainly recommended, you certainly don't want to risk your production code. I would create a temporary repository to test with, or if that is difficult, then a test branch (or even a test folder in the same branch) in your main repo.

Answer (score 2):

Mightymuke is actually right:

Here are the instructions:

1. note all revisions of the new created file (I call them R1 .. to Rn)
2. note revision when original file was deleted(I call it Rd)
3. check out working copy with at least this file
4. delete new file and commit change and state in commit message that File was added wrong in commit R1 (state the revision and make sure everybody can understand why it was wrong added)
5. make an update of your workingcopy ('svn update')
6. if using tortoiseSVN, use show log and locate Rd in history, click on it and right click on the deleted file and choose "Revert changes from this revision" Do not use this on the whole revision, because then you would undo other changes as well. On other OSes use a reverse merge for this("-c-Rd" means for example "-c-50" if 50 was revision of your deleted file):

   svn merge -c-Rd
7. copy the current file contents from the deleted file into the revived on and commit(state the undoing Revisions R2..Rn in your commit message). Alternative: you can recreate each  of the old revisions and commit them separately(state the original revision R2...Rn in each commit message)

Comment: I'm not using tortoiseSVN, I'm using the command line svn client on Linux. I don't know what your #5 "make update" means. Your #6 is the part I don't know how to do. I know how to use 'svn merge' to revert a commit, but will that really restore the original file with it's history?

Comment: yes it will make a svn copy of the previously removed file and keep its history. You can check this with svn status before committing after #6 You can see a "A" and a "+" for the status of the revived file. This means you copy the file from another place(or revision) in repo sharing the same history.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an old question, but it doesn't seem to have a simple answer yet.

The problem originally described is easy to do.  In one commit you delete a file.  In a later commit you re-add the file.  This breaks the svn history between the two files with the identical name.

The fix is simple. You would need to do an `svn rm` of the most recent file, `svn cp` the proper pre-deleted file revision, then manually update the file with the latest updates and check it back in.

For example, suppose myFile.h was deleted in revision 1234:

```
$ cp myFile.h myFile.h.latest        # save copy of latest edits.
$ svn rm myFile.h                    # remove file from svn
$ svn cp myFile.h@1233 myFile.h      # restore the pre-deleted revision (along with history)
$ cp myFile.h.latest myFile.h        # overwrite local copy with latest edits
$ svn ci myFile.h                    # save to SVN
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the commands:

```
$ svn log affected   # Find the last rev that is good, and write it down.
$ svn rm affected
$ svn ci -m'Reverting to save.' affected
$ svn cat -rGOOD_REV affected > affected
$ svn up # important
$ svn add affected
$ svn ci -m'Readding damaged file.' affected
$ svn up # important
# Get revisions after bad import
$ svn diff -rBAD_REV:BAD_REV_PLUS_ONE > diff1.txt
$ patch -p0 < diff1.txt
$ svn ci -m'Rescued -rBAD_REV_PLUS_ONE.' affected
$ svn diff -rBAD_REV_PLUS_ONE:BAD_REV_PLUS_TWO > diff2.txt
$ svn ci -m'Rescued -rBAD_REV_PLUS_TWO.' affected
```

Comment: It doesn't matter, because I have the revision number already, but your first command won't work. 'svn log affected' will stop before the last good revision.  Also, could you please explain how running 'svn rm' and then putting the file back and running 'svn add' restores the original history? It seems to me that would put me back into the same situation I'm already in, with the history starting from the commit right after that 'svn add'.